# Photoelectric effect in hydrogen: evaluating the matrix element integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect, fermis-golden-rule

I'm following page 503 of Shankar's Principle of Quantum Mechanics. The author is discussing the photoelectric effect and transition from the hydrogen ground state to a plane wave. Applying the electric dipole approximation, the matrix element in Fermi's golden rule is
$$H^1_{fi}=\langle f^0|H^1|i^0\rangle = \langle\mathbf{p}_f|H^1|100\rangle$$
$$=N\int e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}\mathbf{A_0}\cdot(-i\hbar\nabla)e^{-r/a_0}d^3\mathbf{r}$$
where $N$ is a constant and $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A_0}\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-wt)$ was the incident wave.

Integrating by parts I get
$$H^1_{fi} = N(-i\hbar)\mathbf{A_0}\cdot [e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0}]_{|\mathbf{r}|\rightarrow \infty} + N\mathbf{A_0}\cdot\mathbf{p}_f\int e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0}d^3\mathbf{r}$$

Am I correct up to this point? My intuition tells me that the first term vanishes since the bound state wave function vanishes at infinity. This would leave me with the desired result in the textbook, namely
$$H^1_{fi} = N\mathbf{A_0}\cdot\mathbf{p}_f\int e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0}d^3\mathbf{r}$$

Is there a more mathematically thorough way of showing that the first term vanishes?

Comment: What do you mean your intuition? The first term includes $e^{-r/a_{0}}$ which vanishes at long distances. However in your formulation you have the dot product of $\bf A_{0}$ with a scalar below the integration by parts. Please double check the $\nabla$ operation on $e^{-r/a_{0}}$.

Comment: I've tried operating on $e^{-r/a_0}$ with $\nabla$, and moving $\nabla$ to the left and operating on $e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0}$, and I can't manage to get the correct answer with either approach. Could you show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What has been your result when you calculated the gradient of $e^{-r/a_{0}}$ as shown in your first equation?

Comment: $\nabla\left(e^{-r/a_0}\right) = \frac{-e^{-r/a_0}}{a_0}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ so I get

$$H^1_{fi} = N(-i\hbar)\mathbf{A_0}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{r}} [e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0}]_{|\mathbf{r}|\rightarrow \infty} + N\mathbf{A_0}\cdot\mathbf{p}_f\int e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0}\mathbf{\hat{r}}d^3\mathbf{r}$$

The first term vanishes, but the second term isn't correct.

Comment: I think you should reword your question based on your comment because from your question it seems that you already got the solution correct but you only have doubt about one of calculation steps.

Comment: I will provide a proof soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, vectors and bold symbols are used interchangeably. Also, various identities are necessary, i.e.:
$$\nabla(fg)=(\nabla f)g+f(\nabla g)$$
$$\nabla\cdot(f\vec V)=\vec V\cdot \nabla f+f(\nabla\cdot \vec V)$$
Also
$$\nabla(e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r})=-\frac{i}{\hbar}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}\vec p_{f}$$
From your first equation
$$H^1_{fi}=\langle f^0|H^1|i^0\rangle = \langle\mathbf{p}_f|H^1|100\rangle=-i\hbar N\vec{A}_{0}\cdot\int e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}(\nabla e^{-r/a_0})d^3\mathbf{r}$$
Now instead of calculating the gradient in the above equation you can use
$$e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}(\nabla e^{-r/a_0})=\nabla(e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0})+\frac{i}{\hbar}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0}\vec p_{f}$$
where I have used the identity $\nabla(fg)=(\nabla f)g+f(\nabla g)$. Subsequently,
$$H^1_{fi}=-i\hbar N\int \vec{A}_{0}\cdot [\nabla(e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0})+\frac{i}{\hbar}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0}\vec p_{f}]d^3\mathbf{r}$$
In other words
$$H^1_{fi}=-i\hbar N\int \vec{A}_{0}\cdot \nabla(e^{-i\mathbf{p}_f\cdot\mathbf{r}/\hbar}e^{-r/a_0})d^3\mathbf{r}+N \vec{A}_{0}\cdot \vec p_{f}\int e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0} d^3\mathbf{r}$$
Now for the first integral and using $\nabla\cdot(f\vec V)=\vec V\cdot \nabla f+f(\nabla\cdot \vec V)$ you have
$$\nabla\cdot(\vec{A}_{0}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0})=\vec{A}_{0}\cdot\nabla(e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0})+e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0}\nabla\cdot \vec{A}_{0}$$
and since $\vec{A}_{0}$ is a constant vector $\nabla\cdot \vec{A}_{0}=0$. Now using the divergence theorem we have
$$\int_{V} \nabla\cdot(\vec{A}_{0}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0}) dV'=\vec{A}_{0} \cdot\int_{\partial V} e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \vec p_{f}\cdot \vec r}e^{-r/a_0} \vec dS'=0$$
since the surface boundary $\partial V$ can be arbitrarily expanded to $r\rightarrow\infty$ and while $dS'$ increases as a function of $r^{2}$, $e^{-r/a_{0}}$ has a faster exponential reduction. Proof complete. Please let me know if you have any further questions and accept the answer if you agree with the solution.